# Yii2 Active Record get the latest record

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following table.

[image]

As you can see there are duplicate school_id. The id field is auto increment so in order to get the latest, I need to get the row with the highest id per school_id.

Using raw sql, the query is like this,

```
SELECT 
rps_checklist.id, school_id,application_type,school_year
FROM rps_checklist
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(id) AS maxx FROM rps_checklist GROUP BY school_id
  ) ms ON rps_checklist.id = maxx
```

and the result I need is the following:

[image]

**P.S I am passing this as searchModel**

Comment: Could you provide the active record models? Have you read the [Active Record section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)?